# Woocommerce and PirateShip

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a very specific question currently using  Woocommerce and shipping is done through pirateship. I have Woocommerce advanced tracking with custom fields however Woocommerce limits what can be imported into pirate. **Which is what I need a custom field to be imported**. I wrote all the php code only to find out that pirate does not offer an api endpoint.

Is there another way I can do this **I was thinking maybe woocommerce rest api**? I cant for the life of me figure thing of anything else and after spending so much time coding I do not want just give up and go with another plugin. to me there has to way woocommerce can allow data retrieval and manipulation.

This is the code I have until pirate ship told me that they do not offer api endpoints: any help is appreciated. Thoughts? Wrote the code only to find out Pirateship does not have api endpoints. I was expecting to add the code and have my custom fields imported into pirate from woocommerce

Comment: Bit confused here: why would you think Pirateship automatically syncs custom fields? You create the fields in Woocommerce, so Pirateship has absolutely no idea of these custom fields. They would have to make new database columns in their system to store the content of these custom fields.  But since they are not aware of custom fields they won’t do that unless you contact the developers and ask them to create this or that custom field.